# Entityform Recaptcha doesn't show notifications

Tags: entities, captcha

I have an entityform in Drupal 7 site that uses the [recaptcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module to protect against spam. It works nicely except for the fact that it doesn't show a warning or notification when it's not filled out/didn't pass.

What could be the problem here? If I change it back to the simpler math captcha then validation does work.